# Problems with drag'n'drop from IE

Tags: c#, internet-explorer

My question is really simple and I don't know whether I am missing something or it is simply not allowed. I am trying to accept any content that has been selected in IE and dragged onto my app. All events fire as they should, and I am starting to analyze the content that I have received and this is where the fun begins.
When I ask for e.Data.GetFormats() in the string array, I can see clearly Text, HTML Format and Rich Text Format amongst other types.

But when I try to e.Data.GetDataPresent("Text") it returns false. Funny enough, when I try e.Data.GetData("Text") I get null too. (Was expected though)

My question is, should I be using something different to handle dragged content from IE? Or simply I can't access the data because it is from Internet Zone?

I forgot to add so later edit: - this is a .NET 2.0 Windows app and not asp.net nor a website :)

Thank you

Comment: Do HTML and RTF formats return empty strings, too?

Answer (score 0):

Use Javascript for handling such tasks, it is fully compatible with the standard browsers.

You may want to program your own jQuery plugin for drag and drop

[Here](http://www.isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/) is one for dragging table rows

Comment: LordCover, thanks for that input it is indeed useful, however I need this for drag'n'dropping content into a Windows Application written in C#, I apologize for the confusion.